# Why does IntelliJ insert a unicode character when I type a key mapped to something else?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, intellij-idea-2018

I use an Emacs-like keybinding set, and when I hit <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> (which is mapped to "Paste from history"), I get "¥" instead.  Is this a Mac thing?  Have I missed some configuration somewhere?

Comment: What Is your keyboard layout?

Comment: Standard US layout.